# How to get return from dispatch() in react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

**Store**

```
reducers: {
 updateProduct: (state, action) => {
  let { id } = action.payload;
  .....
  .....
  .....
  }
}
```

**Dispatching from a function in component**

```
let dispatch = useDispatch();
dispatch({ type: 'products/updateProduct' });
```

**How can I know that product is updated successfully**

**I want something like this**

```
reducers: {
 updateProduct: (state, action) => {
  let { id } = action.payload;
  .....
  .....
  return true;
  }
}
=============
let dispatch = useDispatch();
let status = dispatch({ type: 'products/updateProduct' });
if(status){
 alert()
}
```

Comment: You can't and it doesn't really make sense to try this in an event based system. It depends on why you are trying to react to the result of the action, but probably your best option is to throw the error/status on the products state slice and have this component consume and react to it.

Comment: can you please show me an example that how can I throw an error/status on the product's state slice in a standard way?

Comment: Well what is the result of this action? Just a state update or something more complicated like an api call? What do you expect status to be? Can you fill out the code.